# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::withTrashed() with form validation

Tags: laravel, eloquent

What's wrong with my validation code ?

```
request()->validate([
        'name'=>['required', Rule::unique('users', 'name')->where(function($query) {
            $query->withTrashed();
        })],
        'email'=>['required', Rule::unique('users')->where(function($query) {
            $query->withTrashed();
        })],
        'password'=>'required|min:6|max:20|confirmed',
        'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|captcha',
    ]);
```

In my User model I declared use `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;` and use `SoftDeletes` trait in the class.

But when I want to validate the data I have this error :

> Call to undefined method
>   Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::withTrashed()

Thank's for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `unique` validation rule does work on a table and not a model. The rule itself has no knowledge about the `User` model, it only knows about the `users` database table.

For this reason, the validation engine does use an `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` instance and not an `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` instance. Unfortunately, the normal query builder cannot work with scopes which prevents you from using `withTrashed()`.

This isn't really an issue though because the global soft deleteable filter isn't even applied when using the unique validation rule. In other words, you don't have to do anything - deleted elements will already be considered anyway.